# C# Reference outer class from property list

Tags: c#, class, oop, object

Given the following classes:

```
class OrderHeader
{
    public int orderNo;
    public List<OrderDetail> dtlRows = new List<OrderDetail>();
}

class OrderDetail
{
    public int rowNo;
    public string info;
}
```

Would it be possible to add a reference in every OrderDetail object in the dtlRows List to reference the parent OrderHeader object?  This is so, given an OrderDetail row on its own, it can know data from the parent header record.

So the class would become:

```
class OrderDetail
{
    public int rowNo;
    public string info;
    public OrderHeader parentHdrRecord;
}
```

Example:

```
OrderHeader h = new OrderHeader();
h.orderNo = 12345;

OrderDetail d = new OrderDetail();
d.rowNo = 1;
d.info = "Test Row";
d.parentHdrRecord = h;

h.dtlRows.Add(d);
```

Is this bad form/hacky?  Is it expensive to do memory-wise?

Comment: why not add orderNo in detail if its unique?

Comment: You might consider a nested class for this case, with a ctor param of the parent (storing the reference) since you could easily access the private members of the parent, which could then get row-index, for example, at run time by method call into parent instead of storing it as a data member which could get out of sync if items were moved, for example.

Answer (score 1):

It is considered bad practice to have objects reference each other as it's considered a circular dependency... However; if you're using Entity Framework Code First this is almost exactly how you achieve a one to many relationship in your database.

Comment: That's kind of where I got the idea.  I've seen it done in entity framework and wondered if it was bad practice to do it with regular classes.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this bad form/hacky?

You can have the "circular dependency" error in Visual Studio only if the classes `OrderHeader` and `OrderDetail` are in different projects. If both are in the same project - then it's fine.

> Is it expensive to do memory-wise?

No. It is just a reference - 64 bit (or 32 bit, depends on the target platform). The same memory size like `long` number.

BUT, and it is depends on your application logic:
In case `OrderDetail` has life of its own, when it's parent is not needed anymore. But you didn't execute `orderDetail.parentHdrRecord = null` then the Garbage Collector won't delete the parent and all if it million children that are not in use.

Comment: "considered a circular dependency" ...  In C# you're obviously allowed to bend / break rules but try this in F#.  Also, tools such as NDepend will flag these objects.  I'm not saying you can't do it because obviously you can.  He was asking is it bad form / hack and I was simply suggesting that following tight, uniform guidelines, yes. But shoot, even EF bends / breaks the rules as I mentioned.